# DISCORD.JS own.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

Heyy, I want to make an owner command with embed, my script is simple to understand but I have an error with the description the embed, I don't know why, there is my code:

```js
  let own = await db.get(`${process.env.owner}.owner`) 
    let ownc = await db.get(`${process.env.owner}.ownercount`) 
    if(ownc === null|| "Nan" )ownc=1
    let p0 = 0;
    let p1 = 30;
    let page = 1;

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   embed.setTitle("Owner")
    .setColor(color)
    .setDescription(!own  ? "None":own.map((user, i) => `[${i}] <@${user}>`).slice(0, 30).join("\n")
       )
        .setFooter(`${page}/${Math.ceil(ownc||1/ 30)} • ${footer}`)
      message.channel.send(embed)
```

Version of discord.js: `12.5.3`
Module for db: `@turph/quickmongo`
Database: `MongoDB`

Comment: Have you checked what `own` is? It doesn't seem to be an array

Comment: And what do you think `if(ownc === null|| "Nan" )` will do?

Comment: I check it and owner = `934172257767546960`

Comment: for the `if(ownc === null|| "Nan" )`, it's if there is no owner ('Nan') or if owner = null, there is 1 owner (me)

Comment: `null` is equal to `NaN` what do you really wanted to get? and you are comparing it using `strict equality operator`

Comment: `if(ownc === null|| "Nan" )` will always return `true` even if `ownc` is a valid value because `"Nan"` as a string is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: As for the other one, not sure what you want with `own.map()` if `own` is a number only.